# AngularJS ng-click and $http post error

Tags: angularjs

**AngularJS**

```
theApp.controller('MenuSideController', ['$scope', 'CategoryService', 
  function ($scope, CategoryService){
    CategoryService.getList()
    .success(function(list){
        $scope.list = list;
    });
    $scope.menuType = function(id) {
        $http.post('post_es.php', {'cat': $scope.username, 'pswd': $scope.userpassword, 'email': $scope.useremail}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.msg != '') {
                $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
            } else {
                $scope.errors.push(data.error);
            }
        }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            $scope.errors.push(status);
        });
    }
  }
]);
```

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="company in list"><a href="#" ng-click="menuType(company.id)">{{ company.name }}</a></li>
```

Using the above I receive this error when `menuType` is clicked

> ReferenceError: $http is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the `$http` service as a dependency.

```
theApp.controller('MenuSideController', [
  '$scope',
  'CategoryService', 
  '$http', 
  function ($scope, CategoryService, $http) {
```

This makes it available for use in the controller. The same goes for filter, directives, and services.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really new to AngularJS and got it now